# Why do I get 429 request in scrapy response even the request count is only 1?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using `scrapy` to crawl a website but I get 429 response.

Below is its output log:

```
2020-06-06 21:39:45 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
INFO:scrapy.extensions.logstats:Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-06-06 21:39:45 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO:scrapy.extensions.telnet:Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-06-06 21:39:45 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (429) <GET https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-aspendale+gardens,+vic+3195/list-1> (referer: None)
2020-06-06 21:39:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (429) <GET https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-aspendale+gardens,+vic+3195/list-1> (referer: None)
INFO:scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror:Ignoring response <429 https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-aspendale+gardens,+vic+3195/list-1>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2020-06-06 21:39:46 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <429 https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-aspendale+gardens,+vic+3195/list-1>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Closing spider (finished)
2020-06-06 21:39:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
INFO:scrapy.statscollectors:Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 343,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2030,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/429': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 11, 39, 46, 255540),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/429': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 50941952,
 'memusage/startup': 50941952,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 11, 39, 45, 901907)}
2020-06-06 21:39:46 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 343,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2030,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/429': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 11, 39, 46, 255540),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/429': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 50941952,
 'memusage/startup': 50941952,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 11, 39, 45, 901907)}
INFO:scrapy.core.engine:Spider closed (finished)
2020-06-06 21:39:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

you can see that the `downloader/request_count` is only 1.

Below is my python code:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/in-aspendale+gardens,+vic+3195/list-1',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        results_container = response.xpath('//div[@class="tiered-results-container"]')
        text = results_container.get()
        print(text)
def handler(event, context):
    logging.info(f'lambda {event}')
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': user_agent,
    })
    c.crawl(TestSpider)
    c.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler(None, None)
```

In my `settings.py` file, I have:

```
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [404, 429]
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 12
```

Comment: Did you have at least one request with valid response on earlier run of  this spider?

Comment: See my answer status code 429 is too many connections. You must be going too fast or not using rotating proxies.

Comment: @Georgiy no. I didn't get any valid response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Status code [429](https://httpstatuses.com/429) means too many connections. There is request count 1 on the downloader because a 429 is a denial and does not pass through the downloader. They are incorrectly serving 429 code to any request they believe is a bot.

After experimentation it is denying me due to missing a cookie header which is set at the initial GET request from the set-cookie header. Here is a few things to try with Selenium as the last option in any scraping project.

1. Try using full headers like below with `COOKIES_ENABLED = True`.

```
Host: www.realestate.com.au
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://duckduckgo.com/
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: Trailers
```

Comment: I added both of these configuration but still get the same error.

Comment: Did you ever get a 200 from the website? They might be incorrectly serving 429 to anybody they think is a scraper. I would guess that at first you were receiving 200s and now after sending too many requests you are getting 429 is that not the case?

Comment: Try enabling cookies in settings and that may resolve the issue. If not try getting the cookies. The website does something weird when you load it. It actually makes 2 get requests the first one sets the cookies and other parameters and the second one serves the page.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. If you don't mind what actually solved your problem was it enabling cookies? If so I'll edit the post to contain only the answer, or you're welcome to do it if you have those privileges. I'll approve them.